# codeigniter - how to query 'left join' with 'where_in' clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

found so many answers but still not working, here is my query with two joins

```
$query = $this->db->select('transaction.*,restaurant.logo_url,restaurant.cover_image_url,restaurant.slug,restaurant.delivery_time,user_points.point AS earned_points')
    ->from('transaction')
    ->join('restaurant', 'transaction.restaurant_id = restaurant.id', 'left')
    ->join('user_points', 'transaction.order_id = user_points.transaction_order_id', 'left')
    ->where_in('order_id', $order_id)
    ->get();
    return ($query->num_rows() < 1) ? null : $query->result();
```

getting all records from transaction table except 'restaurant' and 'user_points' tables

is there any problem with joins?

Comment: did you gettting any errror?

Comment: @VijaySharma records are coming without any error, but the column i am selecting with joins is not getting the records

Comment: You means to say that `restaurant.logo_url,restaurant.cover_image_url,restaurant.slug,restaurant.delivery_time,user_points.point AS earned_points` these columns are not coming on result?

Comment: @VijaySharma exactly

Comment: can you share the result what you getting? means `print_r()` the result

Comment: You might want to check the array you are using with `where_in` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180453/activerecord-where-in-with-array

Comment: @Arsee just share one array so i can come to know what the result

Comment: @VijaySharma `$order_details = $this->order_transactions_model->get_user_multi_transaction($order_id);` here how i am storing the result

Comment: @Arsee just share `print_r($query->result());` result

Comment: @Arsee `$this->db->select('transaction.*,restaurant.logo_url,restaurant.cover_image_url,restaurant.slug,restaurant.delivery_time,user_points.point AS earned_points',false);` try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
$query = $this->db->select('transaction.*,restaurant.logo_url,restaurant.cover_image_url,restaurant.slug,restaurant.delivery_time,user_points.point AS earned_points',false)
    ->from('transaction')
    ->join('restaurant', 'transaction.restaurant_id = restaurant.id', 'left')
    ->join('user_points', 'transaction.order_id = user_points.transaction_order_id', 'left')
    ->where_in('order_id', $order_id)
    ->get();
    return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use the following structure. I know it requires a couple of more lines, but is easier to understand and maintain.

```
$condition = 'condition';

$t1 = 'table1_name';
$t2 = 'table2_name';
$t3 = 'table3_name';
$get = [
    $t1.'.columna',
    $t1.'.columna',
    $t2.'.columna',
    $t2.'.columna',
    $t3.'.columna',
    $t3.'.columna'
]
$this->db->select($get);
$this->db->from($t1);
$this->db->join($t2, $t1.'.columna = ' . $t2.'.comlumna', 'left');
$this->db->join($t3, $t1.'.columna = ' . $t3.'.comlumna', 'left');
$this->db->where($t1.'.columna', $condition);
$result = $this->db->get()->result();
```