# why is this happening in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

```
$query1 = $this->db
    ->select('skill_description.description, count(staff_info.staffId) as experienced')
    ->from('skill_rating')
    ->join('staff_info','staff_info.staffId = skill_rating.staffId')
    ->join('skill_description','skill_rating.descriptionId = skill_description.descriptionId')
    ->where ('skill_rating.rating','2')
    ->group_by("skill_description.description")                       
    ->order_by("skill_description.description asc")
    ->get();
```

when I use this I get desired result.. but as soon as I add

```
->where_in ('skill_description.description',$array)
```

it results a null array which it shouldn't. It should return the same result I think. And if I use the pure sql style for the same query, it works. 
$array contains all the descriptions.
what should I do?

Comment: make sure `$array` is an array data

Comment: @pradeep
Array ( [0] => Ab Initio [1] => Ajax [2] => Android [3] => ANT [4] => Appworx - UC4 [5] => C++ [6] => Coreldraw [7] => Crystal Reports [8] => CSS  )   

 this is the $array

Comment: better use `description id` instead of `description name`

Comment: edit your question and add your pure sql query over there

Comment: If description field has text value then you should use ->like() instead of where_in()

Comment: $q = $this->db->select('*')
->from('table')
->where("(col LIKE '%".$search_string1."%' OR col LIKE '%".$search_string2."%' OR col LIKE '%".$search_string3."%' OR col LIKE '%".$search_string4."%')", NULL, FALSE)
->get()->results;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180453/activerecord-where-in-with-array/17180630

Answer (score -1):

IF description has string or text datatype then you should go with LIKE.

```
 $q = $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('table')
    ->where("(col LIKE '%".$search_string1."%' OR col LIKE '%".$search_string2."%' OR col LIKE '%".$search_string3."%' OR col LIKE '%".$search_string4."%')", NULL, FALSE)
    ->get()->results;
```